# Regular expression to check for sequence of numbers(0 to 9)

Tags: regex, perl, numbers, sequence

I am trying to build three regular expression:

1. Regular expression to match a number that is ONLY composed(does not just contain) of a sequence of numbers like:

   23456789

   0123

   12345678
2. Regular expression to match a number that contains ONLY 2 repeating numbers:

   010101

   60606
3. Regular expression to match a number containing either 1 or 2 leading 0s:

   0459897

   00678543

Can someone please provide regular expressions for these?

Comment: How can you expect to create a regular expression when you can't describe exactly what you want in English?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question with proper explanation about what I am looking for. Please take a look and let me know if it requires more clarification.

Comment: so the first one is if the numbers are going up/ascending? and it doesn't matter if the number of consecutive ascending numbers?

Comment: the last one is easy, 
^0{1,2}

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far and the problems you're running into.

Comment: @drmcchamburgers Yes, for first question. I am not sure what your second question is

Comment: Since you tagged this Perl, my solution would be to not use regular expressions, since they are a poor choice for these requirements (except the last one, which is trivial).

Comment: Still for the first requested regular expression, does it matter how many consecutive numbers in a row, could be 3 or 15, or is there a number of digits that you would be expecting

Comment: @drmcchamburgers I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Since there are only 10 digits, I don't think it should exceed 0123456789. I don't want a number to match if it CONATINS a sequence, like 497123456

Answer (score 2):

A substring of `0123456789`:

```
'0123456789' =~ /\Q$string_to_match/
```

```
index('0123456789', $string_to_match) >= 0
```

```
$string_to_match =~ /
   ^
   (?: 0(?:1(?:2(?:3(?:4(?:5(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?
   |       1(?:2(?:3(?:4(?:5(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?
   |           2(?:3(?:4(?:5(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?)?)?)?
   |               3(?:4(?:5(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?)?)?
   |                   4(?:5(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?)?
   |                       5(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?
   |                           6(?:7(?:89?)?)?
   |                               7(?:89?)?
   |                                   89?
   |                                    9
   )?
   \z
/x
```

A substring of `0123456789` of length `$n` or more:

```
length($string_to_match) >= $n && '0123456789' =~ /\Q$string_to_match/
```

```
length($string_to_match) >= $n && index('0123456789', $string_to_match) >= 0
```

A one or more repeating pair of ASCII digits:

```
$string_to_match =~ /^ ([0-9]{2}) \1* \z/x
```

An arbitrarily long sequence of characters that consists of exactly two different ASCII digits:

```
$string_to_match =~ /^ ([0-9]) \1* ([0-9]) \2* (?: \1+ | \2+ )* \z/x
```

An arbitrarily long sequence of characters that consists of exactly two different ASCII digits, where every character must be different than the preceding one:

```
$string_to_match =~ /^ ([0-9]) ([0-9]) (?: \1\2 )* \1? \z/x
```

One or more ASCII digits leading with exactly 1 or 2 zeroes:

```
$string_to_match =~ /^ 0{1,2} (?: [1-9] [0-9]* )? \z/x
```

Notes:

- Instead of `[0-9]`, you can use `\d` with the `/a` flag.

Comment: For substring of 0123456789, could you please provide a regular expresiion? I am not using a language. I am using a tool in which i need to add a regex which is compatible in perl.

Comment: `0|01|012|0123|...|1|12|123|...`

Answer (score 0):

Given your description, I'd start with:

```
/\d{8} \d{4} \d{8}/
```

for the first, and

```
/0{1,2}\d*/
```

for the last.  It's not clear what you mean by "two repeating numbers", so I can't begin to say what the second might be. Do you mean that it only contains two specific digits, and that they must alternate like those shown? I'm not sure that's doable in a regex.

Comment: `\d` matches 370 different characters. You want `[0-9]` or use `/a`.

Comment: OP didn't specify either way.

Comment: You really think it's likely the OP wants to accept `೨೩`!?! If you think it's even possible that they don't, you should at least mention that your pattern might not do the right thing!

Comment: Given the ambiguity of the question, I think it's unlikely the OP even knows whether or not he wants to accept other possible digits.

Comment: All the more reason to mention the two possibilities instead of assuming they meant one of them.